# Question about $E(|Z|)$ at Normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$Z$ is a standard normal variable.
How do I calculate $E(|Z|)$?
($E(Z)=0$).

Thank you!

Comment: Use $E(g(Z))=\int_{z \in \mathbb{Z}}\,g(z)f_Z(z)\,dz$

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma, but I don't understand how...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $|z| = -z \cdot 1_{(-\infty,0)}+ z \cdot 1_{(0,\infty)}$.

The distribution is symmetric about zero, so $E|z| = 2 \int_0^\infty z P(z) dz$, where $P(z) = {1 \over \sigma \sqrt{ 2 \pi }} e^{- { z^2 \over 2 \sigma^2 }}$.

Since $P'(z) = (- { 1 \over \sigma^2 }) z P(z)$, we see that
$E|z| = - { 2 \sigma^2} \int_0^\infty P'(z) dz  = { -2 \sigma^2}(\lim_{z \to \infty } P(z)-P(0)) = { 2 \sigma^2}P(0) = \sqrt{ 2 \over \pi} \sigma$.

Comment: So it's: 
$$2\cdot \frac {1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty x\cdot e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$$

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you! But why you add $\sigma$ at you answer?

Comment: Let me check my algebra...

Comment: I mean at: $$P(z) = {1 \over \sigma \sqrt{ 2 \pi }} e^{- { z^2 \over 2 \sigma^2 }}$$

Comment: That's the probability density of a Gaussian? If $z \sim { \cal N} (0,1)$ then take $\sigma = 1$.

Comment: So the final answer is: 1 (if $\sigma=1$).

Comment: Hold on, I have made a mistake.

Comment: I believe the final answer should be $\sqrt{ 2 \over \pi }$.

Comment: Can I calculate the value immediately from the integral? i.e.
$$2\cdot \frac {1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty x\cdot e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}=\sqrt{ 2 \over \pi}$$ Thank you!

Comment: Yes, because  $\int_a^b f'(x) dx = f(b)-f(a)$.

Comment: Thank you so much! it's much more clear to me know...:-)

Answer (score 2):

$\int\left|x\right|\phi\left(x\right)dx=2\int_{0}^{\infty}x\phi\left(x\right)dx=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}dx$

Now exploit substitution $u=\frac{1}{2}x^{2}$

Comment: The final answer is $\sqrt{\frac2\pi}$ right?

Comment: Yes, it that is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$ E[ |Z| ] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}|z| e^{-z^2/2}dz = 2\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}ze^{-z^2/2}dz$$

From here, this integral is straightforward to compute.

Comment: And the final answer is: $\sqrt{ 2 \over \pi}$?

Comment: yes it is true.