# Is this altered formula for correlation still bounded by $-1$ and $1$?

Tags: statistics, correlation

Recall that

$$
‐1 \le \text{corr}(X,Y) = \frac{\text{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y} \le 1
$$

The proof for this bound uses the [Cauchy Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Probability_theory), and I've been trying to wrap my head around why this bound holds intuitively.

**Question:** Does this bound still hold for the *altered* formula

$$
‐1 \le \frac{\text{Cov}(X,Y)}{d_X d_Y} \le 1
$$

where

$$
d_X = E[|X - E[X]|]
$$

and

$$
d_Y = E[|Y - E[X]|]?
$$

I know that

$$
d_X d_Y \le \sigma_X \sigma_Y
$$

so that, if it did hold, this would be a tighter bound than the original.

Answer (score 2):

The bound doesn't hold for the altered formula. If $X$ is a standard normal variable, then $\operatorname{Cov}(X,X)=\operatorname{Var}(X)=1$ while $d_X= E|X| =\sqrt{\frac2\pi}$ (derivation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/805674/215011)). Therefore
$$\frac{\operatorname{Cov}(X,X)}{ d_X d_X}=\frac\pi2,$$
which is greater than $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=-1$ with probability $2/3$, and $2$ with probability $1/3$, and let $Y=X$.

Compute. We have $d_X=d_Y=4/3$, and $\text{Cov}(X,Y)=2$. The ratio is $\frac{18}{16}$.